# Como customizar os plots do matplotlib, de uma forma mais voltada para clusterização?

Tags: python, plot, k-means, clusterização

Estou trabalhando com clusterização de dados, preciso deixar os dados mais distantes dos clusters representados de alguma outra forma, como um simbolo diferente ou alguma cor mais forte, dei uma analisada na documentação mas não achei nada do gênero. A logica que pensei foi de um dado com distancia N do cluster tenha essa alteração, estou aplicando a tecnica de clustering do sckit-learn.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os dados circulados seriam um exemplo dos que desejo aplicar isso.

Answer (score 1):

Até onde eu consegui encontrar, não existe uma ferramenta que dê a diferença entre os pontos ou dizer quais estão mais perto ou longe. Minha sugestão é usar outras funções pra fazer esta diferenciação.

Existem algumas maneiras de você fazer isso. Eu usei o [`norm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) do `numpy`, mas talvez o [`transform` do kmeans](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) seja uma opção melhor no final das contas.  Depende de como você está a tratar os dados, eu prefiro via `numpy` pois estou mais acostumado a trabalhar direto com os números.

Trabalhei em 2D pra ser mais fácil de demonstrar, mas o método é valido pra 3D também, basta apenas mudar os plots (e os dados inicias, claro).  Minha maneira foi:

1. Fazer um cluster (usei o `numpy`),
2. Usar o k-means para achar os clusters e seus centros com o `fit`,
3. Separar os pontos por cluster e calcular a distância (usando o `norm`) entre os pontos e seus respectivos centros,
4. Separar os pontos que a distância é maior que a média das distâncias.
5. Plotar os pontos de maneira a diferenciar entre os mais próximos e ou demais.

Notas

- Em geral você tem que definir onde está o seu "corte" que diferencia qual ponto está perto ou longe. Eu usei qualquer valor maior que a média, mas em geral isto não é perfeito. Já coloquei um fator (`factor`) multiplicando a média. Assim basta trocar o valor de `factor` para ter uma saída diferente, sem ter que estar mexendo nas partes mais centrais do script.
- Fiz varias variáveis, basicamente uma para cada plot. Isto obviamente não é necessário, mas achei que assim é mais simples para expor como o código funciona. Se você seguir este caminho para separar os pontos, em geral só usando os indices lógicos (tal qual eu separa os pontos externos) já é suficiente.

Abaixo segue o código que fiz.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

#fator the ajuste quanto fora está seu limite
factor=1.0 #usa qq valor maior que a média

a=np.random.rand(50,2)
b=np.random.rand(30,2)*0.15+0.2  #cluster 1
c=np.random.rand(30,2)*0.15+0.6  #cluster 2
d=np.concatenate((a,b,c))  

fig, ax=plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(d[:,0],d[:,1])
plt.show()

#separa os clusters
cl=KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(d)

#só pra verificar
cl.cluster_centers_ #centros
d[cl.labels_==0].size
d[cl.labels_==1].size
d.size

#separa os dados
datac0=d[cl.labels_==0]
datac1=d[cl.labels_==1]

#segundo plot
fig2, ax2=plt.subplots()
ax2.scatter(datac0[:,0],datac0[:,1],c=[ 0, 0, 1])
ax2.scatter(datac1[:,0],datac1[:,1],c=[ 1, 0, 0])
plt.show()


#distancia dos pontos aos seus respectivos centros
distdata0=datac0-cl.cluster_centers_[0]
distdata1=datac1-cl.cluster_centers_[1]

#pontos externos
#aqui separa os valores que são maiores que a media das distâncias
#usei a "norm" pra calcular a distância absoluta entre o ponto e o seu respectivo centro
#depois comparo este valor a media das distâncias, se for maior, vai pra lista
meandist0=np.mean(np.linalg.norm(distdata0,axis=1))
meandist1=np.mean(np.linalg.norm(distdata1,axis=1))
outc0=datac0[np.linalg.norm(distdata0,axis=1) >factor*meandist0]
outc1=datac1[np.linalg.norm(distdata1,axis=1) >factor*meandist1]

#plot os pontos mais externos marcados com "x"
fig3, ax3=plt.subplots()
ax3.scatter(datac0[:,0],datac0[:,1],c=[ 0, 0, 1])
ax3.scatter(datac1[:,0],datac1[:,1],c=[ 1, 0, 0])
#Plota os pontos mais externos "marcados"
ax3.scatter(outc0[:,0],outc0[:,1],c=[ 0, 1, 1],marker='x')
ax3.scatter(outc1[:,0],outc1[:,1],c=[ 1, 1, 0],marker='x')
plt.show()
```

Isto dá o resultado com estes 3 gráficos

[image: Babou][image: Babou][image: Babou]

Com as imagens originais em : [Pontos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1hPD.png), [Clusters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/js4rj.png), [Clusters e pontos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwrYG.png).

Comment: Opa, cara bem interessante as a ideias e os métodos que tu propôs, acho que realmente vai solucionar meu problema, vou ver as adaptações necessárias, enfim obrigado, recém to me adaptando a trabalhar com "data science".